# Bottom slide up layout doesn`t run JAVA class context contents

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have problem with bottom slide up layout in Android Studio (Java). I will try to describe my problem as good as I can.
Alright. I have built Bottom slide up layout with it`s related Java class. In google map activity I have marker onclicklistener function. When I click on marker the bottom slide up layout showup, But the problem is. It just show the front-end of layout (the content I already have in .xml file) but it does Not load or execute's the Java class related to that .xml slide up layout.

That's the only problem. The slide up layout shows up when clicked on google map marker. Main and general Problem is. It does Not execute slide up layout related java class(tools:context=".java_class") functions(context content). I don`t know where is the problem.

Below is the code from my bottom sheet layout which is slides up layout design content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottomSheetContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
    tools:context=".Bottom_sheet_layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/userTopInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:paddingBottom="100dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_marginTop="-100dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:padding="3dp"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/TopInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_sheet_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/linearLayoutID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dbText1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Brand"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dbText2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="text from Database"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And below is a map activity where google map is with marker onClickListener function.

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker1 -> {
//marker1.hideInfoWindow();

Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity.this,Locale.getDefault());
try {
     addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(marker1.getPosition().latitude,marker1.getPosition().longitude, 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
//String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Marker onclicked. Slideup shows.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
// Down below is the code which takes care of bottom layout slide up functionality. Of course this 
// code works it does show slide up layout mentioned, but that layout does NOT do any related java
// context functions. 
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(MapsActivity.this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme);
View bottomSheetView = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_bottom_sheet, findViewById(R.id.bottomSheetContainer));
bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
bottomSheetDialog.show();
return true;
});
```

This is it. This is the code which should work but Not. I meant slideup it self.. Yes it slide's up the layout. But not executed any java class functions even onCreate() wasn't executed after layout slide up. I have tested added some simple Toast() message to onCreate() to make sure it was or wasn't loaded. Nop! Toast didn't appeared that means onCreate() and any other public void function() didn't executed.
PS - I do use "binding" for this slide up layout class. If that matters and few of google firebase functions for data setting and getting.

Any help appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`tools:context` attribute is just a hint to which class this view belongs. It does nothing.

You should create your own `BottomSheetDialog` and set this layout in `onCreateView` method. There are quite a lot of articles about bottom sheets, check [this one](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/bottom-sheet-dialogs-using-android-studio/) out for instance.